# Can a winrt application run as a windows service, on win10/win2012?

Tags: .net, windows, windows-runtime

If my winrt applications is a background process, non visual, can it run as a windows service?

It needs to either auto start (by OS, like a service), or a regular windows service needs to be able to start it. (Or other way that gives same result.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If my winrt applications is a background process, non visual, can it
>   run as a windows service?

You can’t run the WinRT application as a windows service. The WinRT app runs in a App Container with a low integrity, it also has its own [app lifecycle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464925.aspx).

*Background tasks are lightweight. Keeping background execution to a minimum ensures the best user experience with foreground apps and battery life.*

**Background task resource constraints**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what kind of service you want to do, you actually **can** use WinRT with windows 10. Check out this build talk and skip to the part about **App Services**: https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2015/3-765

Comment: We want a regular window service, to run on win10 and win2012-R2.... just described here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Yeah, than you don't want a WinRT solution :)